# Vim: insert mode is very slow with 400+ lines

Tags: vim, line

I have a file with 400+ lines (it's a thesis). When I edit it somewhere near
the top (say, on line 20), Vim is snappy as always. However, editing it near
the bottom (around line 400) causes a noticeable delay between me typing the character
and Vim showing it on the screen. As a consequence, it is almost impossible to
edit a file this big.

What is the reason for this and what can I do?

I've tried toggling the `swapfile`, `syntax`, `scrolloff` etc, but it doesn't
seem to help. The maximum number of lines for Vim should be 2147483647, so I
should actually have a long way to go here :)

In case this is related to setting `maxmem`, then what would be a reasonable
value, considering that I edit files up to 2500 lines?

Thanks very much for any help! Cheers.

Comment: try starting vim with `vim -u NONE`. Same behavior?

Comment: usually 400,2500 lines are just a piece of cake for vim. how big is your file size?

Comment: 400 lines is small, so is 2500. Do you use `set wrap`? What is the length of the longest lines? What filetype do you use? What, if any, plugins do you use? What version of Vim? What OS? Shell or GUI?

Comment: @Fredrik this seems to work. That means the problem is somewhere in my settings, right?

Comment: @Kent yeah, that's what I'm thinking, too. It's only 20.4 kilobytes :/

Comment: yes, problem is probably in some plugin/setting.  No easy way to find where though. Just comment everything out in your `.vimrc` and add piece by piece until problem returns...

Comment: Thanks. @romainl I have `set wrap`; filetype is `pandoc` (maybe this is the problem, thought setting ft to `TEXT` didn't help). Vim 7.3 in Crunchbang Linux + URXVT. But I've had the same problem in other systems as well. So it must be my current settings. I'll go through my .vimrc line-by-line then. Thanks a bunch so far!

Comment: Post your vimrc if you need some help and try `:set nowrap`.

Comment: Okay, it `vim-pandoc` is slowing things down. This is a reported trouble with that (awesome!) plugin. I had do disable folding for the plugin, and now Vim flies again. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently came across this exact problem - lag while typing at the bottom of a relatively short (markdown) file. After uninstalling plugins and commenting out most of the settings in my .vimrc, I discovered that the issue was markdown folding coming from the [vim-markdown plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown) that is pre-installed with vim. Commenting out `let g:markdown_folding = 1` did the trick.

I still wanted to have automatic folding on markdown files, so I installed [vim-markdown-folding](https://github.com/masukomi/vim-markdown-folding) and there are no issues with performance.

Comment: Thanks for the input! This was a long time ago, but I was definitely also using Markdown in vim when this happened. Not sure if it was vim-markdown, VOoM or some other plugin with outlining capabilities at that time, though. But, indeed, I was surely writing long Markdown documents with a folding view in another window when this happened. Glad you got it sorted out as well.

Answer (score 18):

Okay, folding was the problem here (I had some bad settings for `foldlevelstart`). So, based on my experiences and [these](https://superuser.com/questions/550669/my-copy-of-vim-is-running-extremely-slowly-when-i-edit-medium-to-large-eg-1000) [issues](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/issues/8):

```
set foldenable              " can slow Vim down with some plugins
set foldlevelstart=99       " can slow Vim down with some plugins
set foldmethod=syntax       " can slow Vim down with some plugins
```

Other things to check/toggle are `syntax`, `filetype`, `wrap` and line length (some plugins can be slow with very long lines).

Running Vim without your current settings is a good starting point. Thanks to @Frederik for pointing me to this:

```
vim -u NONE
```

After this, disabling all plugins is a good start. See also for general knowledge: `:help slow`

Comment: Had some speed problems with +10 lines pasting and disabling the folding (vim_markdown in my case) solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

In my case relative numbers with same file opened in multiple windows was lagging. I had to do either `:set norelativenumber` or close another windows.

Comment: Thanks. This solved laggy typing in a markdown file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't blame syntax only, several things can slow down editing in normal mode. e.g. auto completion; I had days of thinking that my Vim was slow because of syntax. I configured my autocompletion plugin to only trigger autocompletion once I have typed in at least 6 characters and the speed grew tremendously. I didn't even have to touch anything with syntax highlighting.

Comment: **Update 2020:**

You might want to check out [coc.nvim][1] to use as your language intellisence engine. It's fantastic and does autocompletion in editing mode asynchronously so you experience will not be slowed down.


  [1]: https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim
vim line