# vim syntax performance with very long lines

Tags: vim, markdown, vim-plugin

I'm using vim to edit markdown files that contain some very long lines (100000
characters). Vim is very slow with this kind of input. If I turn off syntax
highlighting (`:syntax off`), Vim is not slow anymore.

The reason for the length is that some of the code blocks contain json that
contain images encoded in base64. (Actually, I'm trying to edit a [markdown
version](https://github.com/aaren/notedown) of an ipython notebook).

Here is what the offending text looks like:

````
```{.json .output n=41}                                                                                                                                                                                              
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
"metadata": {},                                                                                                                                                                                                    
"output_type": "display_data",                                                                                                                                                                                     
"png": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAtAAAAFxCAYAAAB....long...long....line...."
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
]                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
```
````

What I'd like is for Vim to not be slow.

Possible solutions that I've thought of:

1. `set synmaxcol=250` - no, breaks syntax highlighting after a long line
2. Disable syntax highlighting selectively for long lines (not sure how to do
   this)
3. Disable syntax highlighting for code blocks that begin with `{.json` (don't
   know how)

I'm using the [vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax)
syntax highlighter. This gives code blocks the syntax group
`pandocDelimitedCodeBlock` or e.g. `pandocDelimitedCodeBlock_json` if you turn
on language detection.

This also means that I'm folding on syntax groups (`foldmethod=syntax`) which
is a possible source of slowness (see [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086155/vim-insert-mode-is-very-slow-with-400-lines)), [github](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/issues/8)) and [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/550669/my-copy-of-vim-is-running-extremely-slowly-when-i-edit-medium-to-large-eg-1000))).
However, `:set foldmethod=manual` does not solve the problem.

Comment: have you soft line-wrap enabled? another thought: readers of your book probably won't enjoy the long lines either, do you really need them?

Comment: `set synmaxcol={low value}` is the only practical solution: you don't want syntax highlighting for those binary blobs.

Comment: @mb21 no soft wrapping. The long lines are only there in production - they get turned into images in publishing.

Comment: @romainl yes, but doing that breaks the syntax highlighting after the long line

Comment: No, [it doesn't](http://i.imgur.com/8j2s7j7.png).

Comment: [this](https://imgur.com/z57vTXU) is what I get

Comment: but yes, your example is correct. It must be something to do with the markdown highlighter.

Comment: Is editing the text an option? Can a string be broken into multiple lines in json?

Comment: @Ben I tried breaking it into 80 char lines, but still very slow. I think that folding is the problem: vim-pandoc does folding based on syntax. I'm currently hacking a foldexpr method to use instead.

Comment: @romainl - Thanks for that. I had a similar problem with very long lines causing the highlighting to break in the middle of the line, and then the rest of the file was broken as well. Setting synmaxcol to a very high value (8000) fixed all of it, and apparently my problem isn't bad enough to cause the slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

[vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc) makes extensive use of syntax folding and I'm pretty sure that is the issue. Disabling vim-pandoc-syntax and turning off folding (`let g:pandoc#modules#disables = ['folding']`) makes vim fast again.

For syntax highlightin I've used my fork of tpope's [vim-markdown](https://github.com/aaren/vim-markdown/tree/dev). I've forked it because the original does not syntax highlight code blocks with pandoc style attributes (pull request [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/pull/74)).

For folding on headers *and* fenced code blocks using a foldexpr I've used my fork of [vim-markdown-folding](https://github.com/aaren/vim-markdown-folding/tree/dev). Forked because the original does not fold on code blocks (pull request [here](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding/pull/13)).

Whilst this doesn't really answer my question (which I agree isn't well defined), it does fix my problem.